# Can I reuse blender animations?

Tags: animation

Before I begin wasting hours of my life, can I reuse blender animations that I made for one model?

Let's say I animate directly a rig armature, then apply it to a character, will it work? or do I to to do idle animations, walks, runs, climbing... and all that stuff for every single model?

Let's say I make a character and then want to change their hair or clothes, do I need to remake all animations over again?

Comment: you can use the same animation for several objects, you'll need to parent the object correctly though

Comment: Further detailing what moonboots has already said: If the skeleton is structured and named exactly (in caps)  the same way, it is possible to copy an animation from one skeleton to another.

Comment: If the skeleton doesn't differ too much, you can remove the mesh, lay another on top and reparent with automatic weighting. Works fine.